# Why am I getting "Invalid object name 'FinishedMappings'." here?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, stored-procedures

I call

```
    public bool CheckIfFinished ( Guid pid, int sid )
    {
        // pid: guid corresponding to partner
        // sid: survey id 
        bool finished = false;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckIfFinished", this._Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
            this._Conn.Open();
            using ( SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    finished = dataReader.GetByte(0) == 1 ? true : false;
                }

            }
            this._Conn.Close();
        }
        return finished;
    }
```

which calls the sproc

```
GO
-- Create sproc for returning whether a partner has marked their survey as finished
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckIfFinished
    @pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @sid INT
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1 FROM FinishedMappings WHERE partner_id=@pid AND survey_id=@sid
  END
```

which uses the table `FinishedMappings` which does exist because it was defined with

```
CREATE TABLE FinishedMappings ( 
    partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    survey_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (partner_id,survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES Partners(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES Surveys(id)
);
```

right above the sproc. Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Try to use fully qualified name ( ie with schema name )

Comment: Command type  = StoredProcedure and You should use output param

Comment: @DimaSUN That would be strange considering that I have used table 1-part table names in every other sproc without problem

Comment: If You like to return Select  then You should use Command type = Text (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

If the table was created using a different user to the one that you are executing the sp with then a fully qualified name could be needed. I would check this first as dimasun suggested in his first reply.

Also check to see if you can execute the sp directly in SQL management studio. If this doesn't work then you can focus on the code in the sp